# Cannot get my Postman HTML report in Azure DevOps CD pipeline

Tags: postman, azure-pipelines, postman-collection-runner

I'm trying to get the Postman HTML report in Azure DevOps for my release pipeline.

Here the tasks.

```
steps:
- task: jungeriusit.jungit-robocopy.jungit-robocopy.Robocopy@1
  displayName: 'Copy Test Collateral'
  inputs:
    source: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_cdproject/Postman'
    destination: 'D:\Automation\Postman'
    files: '*.json,*.xml,*.ps1,*psm1,*.txt,*.cmd,*.html'
    copySubDirs: true
    copySubDirsAll: false
    purge: true
    move: false
    createtree: false
    excludeFiles: '*.md'
    excludeDirs: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_cdproject\Postman\Archive $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_cdproject\Postman\DocumentsAndOthers $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_cdproject\Postman\SDS $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_cdproject\Postman\SharePoint 
    retries: 3

    - task: UseNode@1
      displayName: 'Node install'
      inputs:
        version: 16.x
        checkLatest: true
    
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm install newman'
      inputs:
        command: custom
        workingDir: 'D:\Automation\Postman\Scripts'
        verbose: false
        customCommand: 'install newman -g'
      continueOnError: true
    
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm install html report'
      inputs:
        command: custom
        workingDir: 'D:\Automation\Postman\Scripts'
        verbose: false
        customCommand: 'install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra'
      continueOnError: true
```

Then I have a PowerShell script doing some other stuff and at the end the newman command.

```
"newman run '" + $runnerFileFullName + $globalSecrets + "' -e '" + $environmentFileFullName + $environmentParam + "' --insecure --disable-unicode --color " + $color + " -r htmlextra --reporters 'cli,junit,json,htmlextra' --reporter-json-export '" + $reportFile + "'"
```

and finally trying to publish reports.

```
- task: MaciejMaciejewski.postman-report.UploadPostmanHtmlReport.UploadPostmanHtmlReport@1
  displayName: 'Upload Postman Html Report'
  inputs:
    cwd: 'D:\Automation\Postman\Scripts'
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.xml'
    searchFolder: 'D:\Automation\Postman\Scripts'
    mergeTestResults: true
    testRunTitle: Results
  continueOnError: true
```

At the end JUnit nor postman report are working, any idea about what can I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i think the path you gave is not right, it looks like from your local system, ideally it should be

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

if you can make below corrections to publish task for **cwd** and **searchFolder**, it should work

This value if you try changing **D:\Automation\Postman\Scripts**

```
steps:
- task: UploadPostmanHtmlReport@1
  displayName: 'Upload Postman Html Report'
  inputs:
    cwd: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    tabName: 'Postman Test'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.xml'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    mergeTestResults: true
    testRunTitle: Results
  continueOnError: true
```